# android studioでwebview配置が失敗します。

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

https://techacademy.jp/magazine/3503
↑を参考にwebviewを配置しただけなのですが、
なぜかエラーが出るのと
(エラー内容をコピーしたいのですが、
コンテキストでコピー選択した瞬間にエラー内容が消えてしまいます。)

android:id="@+id/webView″
この部分が自動で反映されません。

何が問題なのでしょうか？
環境はwindows10 android studio 2.3

Comment: 最悪手打ちでもいいので、エラー内容を追記してください。スクリーンショットを撮られているようなのでエラー表示中のスクリーンショットを撮ることもできるはずです。この質問の仕方では回答がつきにくいと思います。

Comment: おそらくこれです。
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817537/this-view-is-not-constrained
ConstraintLayout が正しく動かせてないかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
参考にさせていただきます。
また、手打ちでもエラー内容を追記すべきでした。。。
大変申し訳ございません。以後気をつけます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://techacademy.jp/magazine/3503
上記のwebviewを配置しているサンプルと比べると、xmlの下記コードが異なります。
こちらで試したところ、下記コードがあることでエラー表示（WebViewに赤い波線が表示）されましたので、まずは下記を削除してみたらどうでしょう。

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
```

> android:id="@+id/webView″
>   この部分が自動で反映されません。

idは自動で設定されません。
このidは下記のようにActivity等から参照するときに使うものです。
`R.id.webView`の`webView`の部分が設定したidの名前となります。

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
無事動作できました。